# Display text (label) not updating

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, solution

I have done a change in my DEV environment (which holds all the `Unmanaged` solutions) on a solution in which there is the `Account` entity.

I made a few changes on display text for specific fields (ex: I had a field whose display text was 'Primary Contact', now has been changed to 'Billing Contact').

In DEV, the changes do come up OK after publishing all customizations, but is not updated in the target TEST environment under which I imported the solution as Managed.

I made sure to increment the version # of said solution and schema names have not changed.

Any ideas ? Thanks.

EDIT: In my DEV env. I did export/import translations and changed the display strings/localized labels to support french, the new french label has made it to the target, but the english label has not. (??).

Comment: did you select "overwrite customizations" when you imported the solution? I mean this step: http://www.magnetismsolutions.com.au/images/roshan/automatically-activate-processes-in-crm-2011-rollup-12-(1).png?sfvrsn=2

Comment: @GuidoPreite Yes, I did!

Comment: Any chance your user in Test does not have their language set to French?

Comment: @Daryl About that point, when I switch to french, I do see the new label for the field. But when I revert to english, I see the old label . In DEV, regardless of the language I use, I see the updated field label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way solutions are handled within CRM 2011/2013 are that unmanaged solutions sit on top of any managed solutions.  It's more than likely you have an unmanaged solution with the account entity included and the "Primary Contact" set as the label.

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC443916.png

Alternatively, this could be related to the UR you are presently on.  Prior to UR12, this was an issue.  To remedy, you can either create a brand new managed solution with this label change or update the roll-up. Unfortunately, incrementing an existing solution doesn't update labels appropriately (prior to UR 12).

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/88156.aspx

Comment: In that case, unzip the managed solution and look at the config to confirm it's bringing in the proper label.

Comment: The `customizations.xml` file nor `solutions.xml` file has any mention of "Primary Contact" in them. `customizations.xml` has the correct labels.

Comment: Oops, "Micosoft CRM Server" is at UR11. Other CRM components are at UR16, but the server component itself is at UR11, both environments.

Comment: Ok, this was fixed in UR12.  You can create a brand new managed solution with this label change or update the roll-up.  Unfortunately, incrementing an existing solution doesn't update labels appropriately.  https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/88156.aspx

Comment: Great thanks. Edit your answer and add that last bit of information to it and I'll mark it as accepted.